# getting error while installing redis python

Tags: python, redis, python-poetry

I am using `poetry` for python application. From `pyproject.toml`, I have created `requirements.txt` file using `poetry export` command. Also, I am using docker-compose.

For `redis`, I am getting error as below:

```
Collecting async-timeout>=4.0.2
ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==. These do not:
    async-timeout>=4.0.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/c1/8991e7c5385b897b8c020cdaad718c5b087a6626d1d11a23e1ea87e325a7/async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (from redis==4.5.4->-r requirements.txt (line 622))


ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

In requirements.txt file

```
redis==4.5.4 ; python_full_version == "3.11.3" \
    --hash=sha256:2c19e6767c474f2e85167909061d525ed65bea9301c0770bb151e041b7ac89a2 \
    --hash=sha256:73ec35da4da267d6847e47f68730fdd5f62e2ca69e3ef5885c6a78a9374c3893
```

Please help.

Comment: I tried upgrading the pip version and poetry version.
`pip: 23.0.1` and `poetry: 1.4.2`

but still getting same error.